# Regular Expression for getting filename

Tags: regex

How to write a regular expression for return file name by trim its extensions,

Following are my files,

```
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-smile.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-laughing.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-wink.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-tongue-out.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-cry.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-surprised.gif
externals/tinymce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-embarassed.gif
```

I would like to get filename without its extension and trim its smiley from staring using regular expresion,

Expected Outputs,

```
smile, laughing, wink, tongue-out, cry, surprised, embarassed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match the text that you are interested in:

```
/smiley-([^.]+)\.[^.]+$/
```

The smiley name will then be present in capture group 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex:

```
.*smiley-(.*?)\.gif$
```

[See it](http://www.rubular.com/r/90u02XbTmm)

The part you want will be in capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/smiley-([\w-]+)\.gif/
```

The part within the parentheses is what you capture.